# is there any way to give custom viewport to useInView hook in react-intersection-observer?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have a list of elements. I want to know the view information of the elements if they cross a custom **viewport**.

I have tried to find a way from google but didn't find anything related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getBoundingClientRect() method to get the position/dimensions of each element. Then you can compare the element's position/dimensions to the viewport's position/dimensions.

This is a simple code to show an idea:

```
var viewport = document.getElementById('custom-viewport');
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var rect = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();

  if (rect.top >= viewport.offsetTop && 
      rect.left >= viewport.offsetLeft &&
      rect.bottom <= (viewport.offsetTop + viewport.offsetHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (viewport.offsetLeft + viewport.offsetWidth)) {
    console.log('Element is inside the viewport');
  }
}
```

Comment: here, by custom viewport, i meant the custom size of the viewport like 120. If a elements crosses the viewport, i want to know some information of the component. Could you share your thoughts on that?

Comment: Maybe you need IntersectionObserver? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API